# Powershell System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

Tags: forms, powershell, output

I am trying to create a GUI for a funktion to remove UUID from SCCM.

I am having trouble to put the value written in my textbox to the confirmation window opened when i click "Delete".

The value is displayed but with "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: ANDWHATWASWRITTEN"

How to extract only the words written in the textfield?

[image]

```
Function Delete()
{  
Write-Host "Your choice is $Result"

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNoCancel
$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Error
$MessageBody = "Are you sure you want to delete the the computer with this UUID: $($UUID.Text)"
$MessageTitle = "Confirm Deletion"
$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)

Write-Host "Your choice is $Result"
}
Function Abort()
{
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.Close()
}

Function Generate-Form {

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Build Form
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.Text = "Delete UUID from SCCM"
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.Width = 362
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.Height = 179
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.Topmost = $True

$ComputerUUID = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Label
$ComputerUUID.Text = "Enter Computer UUID"
$ComputerUUID.AutoSize = $true
$ComputerUUID.Width = 25
$ComputerUUID.Height = 10
$ComputerUUID.location = new-object system.drawing.point(100,12)
$ComputerUUID.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10,style=Bold"
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.controls.Add($ComputerUUID)

$UUID = New-Object system.windows.Forms.TextBox
$UUID.Width = 202
$UUID.Height = 20
$UUID.location = new-object system.drawing.point(71,39)
$UUID.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.controls.Add($UUID)

# Add Button
$Delete = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Delete.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,80)
$Delete.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$Delete.Text = "Delete"

# Add Button
$Cancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Cancel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(175,80)
$Cancel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$Cancel.Text = "Cancel"

$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.Controls.Add($Delete)
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.Controls.Add($Cancel)

#Add Button event 
$Delete.Add_Click({Delete})
$Cancel.Add_Click({Abort})


#Show the Form 
$DeleteUUIDfromSCCM.ShowDialog()| Out-Null 

  } #End Function 

  #Call the Function 
  Generate-Form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `Text` property of the `TextBox` object, not the object *itself*:

```
"Are you sure you want to delete the the computer with this UUID: $($UUID.Text)"
```

Comment: Worked lika a charm! Thank´s!